# Accessing some files from master in gh-pages branch

Tags: json, git, github, github-pages

I am creating a GitHub Pages site for my project. [GitHub advises](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/) generating an orphan `gh-pages` branch and clearing all existing files from the branch. For my site to work, I'll need copies of the latest revisions of several JSON files from `master` in the `gh-pages` branch (and without them, jQuery `$.getJSON()` won't work, as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612800/load-json-from-github-file)).

It seems that there are (at least) two approaches to getting files from `master` into `gh-pages`.

#### 1. Create `gh-pages` branch from `master` and then rebase `gh-pages` regularly.

This approach is summarized [here](http://lea.verou.me/2011/10/easily-keep-gh-pages-in-sync-with-master/), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1708339/2471874) discusses how to automate this process. I think the trouble with this approach is that the history of the site is now linked with the entire history of the rest of the repo, even though the history in `master` isn't particularly important to the site. The `gh-pages` branch might also end up with a lot of content from `master` that isn't needed for the site.

#### 2. Use `git-checkout` to pull just the needed files from `master` into `gh-pages` regularly.

This method involves a non-traditional use of `git-checkout`, described [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/git-checkout-specific-files-from-another-branch/), to copy files from one branch into another. The branch would be an orphan, as suggested by GitHub, but could still include the JSON files in `master` by pulling them in with `git-checkout`. My hesitation with this approach is that it means creating a commit in `gh-pages` each time the files are updated from `master`, which seems extraneous, since the history will then have a bunch of commits that say "Updating JSON files from master."

I'm leaning towards not worrying about the extra commits and using approach #2, but is there another approach I should consider? Are there any important advantages/disadvantages of the approaches above that I might have missed?

Comment: It"s very difficult to get it. Why do you need to use files in several branches. Your process is quite strange. Do you have a github repository ?

Comment: I have [a repo](https://github.com/trynthink/dogs) I'm using for testing purposes. There's a gh-pages branch already set up. If the original post was unclear, let me know what I should explain better.

Answer (score 0):

#### Github pages processing

1. Once pulled to your publishing branch (`gh-pages` for project
   repository or `master` for a user repository (eg :
   username.github.io)) your site is generated using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/)
   processing.
2. An other option is to instruct github pages not to use jekyll processing
   but just copy files from publishing branch. This is done by creating
   a `.nojekyll` file at the root of you repository.

#### Suggested process

In your case the idea can be to version both python scripts and web site files in `gh-pages` branch.

```
|-- _python_scripts
|   |-- script.py
|   |-- ...
|-- index.html
|-- script.js
|-- dogs.json
```

Using the first processing mechanism (with jekyll) this will result in `_python_script` folder being ignored for publication, and all other files being published.

#### Conclusion

You have a clear process with a commit history for datas gathering, processing and presentation. This the project history and from my point of view datas history is as important as presentation history, maybe more.

My two cents.

Comment: Forgive me if the answer is obvious, but how could *.py files in / on `master` be in a folder /_python_scripts on `gh-pages`? Are you proposing that I put any files on `master` that I want ignored on `gh-pages` into folders (for both branches) that start with '_'?

Comment: Yes everything in gh-pages branch and _ prefixed folder for files that are part of the sources and don't need to be published on web site.